# How to use default values in a powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, powershell

In my script I got this :

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$csvFileName = 'thisfile.csv',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$sharePointWebUrl= 'https://mysite'
 )
```

When I run the script it returns this error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'csvFileName' because it is an 
empty string.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not mandatory if you are supplying a default value.

Just run it this way to supply values or use the defaults:

```
param (
    [Parameter()][string]$csvFileName = 'thisfile.csv',
    [Parameter()][string]$sharePointWebUrl= 'https://mysite'
 )
```

or this way to always require the parameters:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$csvFileName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$sharePointWebUrl
 )
```

But not both...